# why ArrayIndexOutOFBoundException in bidirectional bubble sort?

Tags: java

I could not understand why this code is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
here is my code to implement bidirectional bubble sort.

```
static void bubble(int[] a){
    int temp;
    for(int i=a.length-1,k=0;i!=k;i--,k++){
        for(int j=k;j<i;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
        for(int j=i-1;j>k;j--){
            if(a[j-1]>a[j]){
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger built into your IDE. Watch `i`, `k`, and `j`, in particular where they're used to access `a` (and allow for the `+1` and `-1` you're using sometimes). You'll find the bug.

Comment: @Shreya Try using an IDE to insert breakpoints and monitor the progress of the code. You should be able to see the scenario where a non-existent index is accessed.

Comment: Debug your code. But, as I see, if `a.length` is even, then `i` is uneven but `k` is even, so you'll never receive `i==k` situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of that line:

```
for(int i=a.length-1,k=0;i!=k;i--,k++)
```

you incremnt k and decrement i, but your just checking for `!=`. But the difference each time is 2, so you will not neccesarily get the `!=`. Try to replace it by `>`:

```
for(int i=a.length-1,k=0;i>k;i--,k++){
```

Comment: yes its working now!! thanks for your help...

Comment: Then please mark my answer  as solution.

Answer (score 1):

if `a.length` is 4, then i=3, k=0.

on next iteration: i=2, k=1.

next: i=1, k=2

next: i=0, k=3, j=k, a[j+1] -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Your outer for never checks for bounds:

```
for(int i=a.length-1,k=0;i!=k;i--,k++){
```

If for any reason `i` will never be equal with `k`, then your `for` cycle will reach `i == -1` and `k == a.length`. If you have an odd number of elements, then when `i` and `k` reach the median, the `for` will stop. But what if the number of elements is pair? Like 10? When `i` reaches 5 and `k` reaches 4, then you increase `k` to 5 and decrease `i` to 4. So they will never be equal. You will need to check for `i >= k` instead if `i!=k`.

Comment: @shreyajain if this answers your question, then you might want to accept it as the correct answer.